# Trying to Run js on firefox - it works fine on linux but not on windows

Tags: windows, linux, firefox, extjs

I wrote a js using ext.

I try checking this script.

When checking is on small data I receive the same result on Firefox Windows and Firefox Linux.
But when I try it on large scale of data Firefox Linux work perfect but for Firefox Windows I get the exception -

```
Component returned failure code: 0x8007000e (NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY)    
[nsIDOMHTMLCanvasElement.width]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that your getting this error because you are trying to display something using Canvas that is too big for FF. Could you post any of your code here or describe the data you are trying to check? I've also heard that this can be an OS based problem are you running Win7 64bit (most commonly sees this error) try running from a 32bit windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. 
Like you said this is a problem of the canvas is too big.
I managed to solve the problem by using Google Chrome.